# Why the values are continuously getting printed since no loop or no next call is given to the PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, json, html, server-sent-events

Following is an demo example of 'Server Sent Events(SSE)':

HTML code(index.html) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code(demo_sse.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: $time\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

The output I got is as follows :

```
Getting server updates
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:00 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:05 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:10 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:15 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:20 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:25 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:30 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:35 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:40 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:46 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:51 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:27:56 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:01 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:06 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:11 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:16 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:21 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:26 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:31 +0530
The server time is: Sun, 31 May 2015 15:28:36 +0530
.
.
.
and so on....
```

So my question is I've written a PHP code to print the server time once then why after certain irregular time interval the output is keep on printing?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the `flush();` in `demo_sse.php`?

Comment: @nhee: To flush the output data back to the web page. To push the message out to the client as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)

> The EventSource interface is used to receive server-sent events. It connects to a server over HTTP and receives events in text/event-stream format *without closing the connection*.

and

> **reconnection time**
>       This is a time, in milliseconds, used to determine how long to wait after a *failed attempt to connect* before trying again.

When you look at the server's log file, you will see that the client connects every few seconds to reestablish the connection. This happens, because the PHP script closes the connection, when it finishes.

When you add a [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep) to the end of the script, e.g.

```php
$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: $time\n\n";
flush();
sleep(600);
```

the connection stays open for some time. Then, the client just waits for new messages and doesn't try to reconnect to the server.